# Resuming git-svn clone: "git svn fetch" starts from scratch

Tags: git, svn, clone

I read on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2676912/619754) that the way to resume an interrupted *git svn clone* is *git svn fetch*.   In my case, the download from the svn server always stalls after a few minutes. I've tried waiting it out overnight, but in the morning it's just where I left it the previous night. I quit with cntr-C.  *git svn fetch* then starts the entire download from the beginning.  Obviously, this gets me nowhere.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it ever downloading anything?  Does the .git directory have any objects?  Maybe it never actually starts, so it starts fresh ever time?

Comment: Yes, it is downloading.  .git has four or five large files, and some zero-length files.  For example :     -rw-------    1 gary  staff  1638400 Feb 27 15:53 c4nsiNdijC
-rw-------    1 gary  staff        0 Feb 28 09:49 c5lPBJfcAz       (sorry about the formatting.  Can't put a newline in a comment, it seems)

Comment: `git svn fetch` works.  I was (and still am) confused because on each restart, a hundred, more or less, file names scroll by that are repeats: they also appeared in the previous two or three or four fetches.  I began to notice new file names scroll by, so I persevered,   and after fifteen or twenty restarts of `git svn fetch` I had everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch partial history first with `git svn -r <revision range>` parameter. Then either to fetch more commits part by part or limit yourself to shallow svn history.

Also ensure you have recent enough git.

Comment: When I do what you suggest, my app doesn't build.  I see two possibilities: 1.) I need to build and bring in libraries not contained in this repo (which is a different issue from the issue at hand).  2.) I don't have a complete snapshot of the current head.  Will `git svn fetch -rxxxx:HEAD` provide a complete copy of the HEAD state of the repository, only with less history?    Furthermore, I cannot add additional history.  `git svn fetch -ryyyy:xxxx` returns silently.

Comment: "svn:externals" is not magically turned to git submodules. You need to supply them manually.

Comment: Just "git svn fetch" should continue up to current revision. Note that you can't normally extend svn history to earlier commits (unlike shallow git clones)