# git svn clone hangs. fetch restarts but hangs at the same place

Tags: git, svn, clone, freeze

I'm trying to *git svn clone* an svn repo.  It gets to a certain point, say at file x.xxx, and hangs.  No network activity.  I ctrl-C and *git svn fetch*.   It restarts the download, but from a point many hundreds of files prior x.xxx.  Then when it gets to x.xxx again some ten minutes later, it freezes again.  I've gone through this cycle about a dozen and a half times.   Actually there are a small set of files in the class with x.xxx, say y.yyy and z.zzz.   After restart it *always* stops at *one* of those files.  Sometimes it gets by an earlier one, but it will eventually hang on one of them.

Is there some way to force it to restart from a point closer to the point at which it hangs?  Is there a way to try to fetch files individually by name?  Is there some setting that I can try to change just to shake things up a bit?

Edit:  This has happened to me [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484649/resuming-git-svn-clone-git-svn-fetch-starts-from-scratch) ... I completely forgot. Nonetheless, the problem remains.

Comment: IMHO, This happens due to a timeout in the perl script.

Comment: is there any workaround?

Comment: @BiswajitMaji  In my case, the problem *appears* to have been due to the transfer of a large file and my internet service provider not being happy about it.   I discovered that everyone in my company would have the problem from time to time.  One day our ISP announced that they were upgrading something.  After that was finished, we no longer had the problem.