# git svn take long time

Tags: git, git-svn, execution-time

While migrating from SVN to GIT, `git svn clone ...` command took almost 54 hrs on RHEL5, 4GB RAM, 2-CPU each@2.67GHz

Is there any way the git-svn cloning time can be reduced?

PS: git-svn checkout data was around 25+ GB. And final bare git repo space is: 939M

Comment: where is the svn repo? have you checked what's the bottleneck (network or CPU)?

Comment: svn repo is hosted on the same server, but i'm using apache to access it. As per internet, above mentioned hardware config is enough for GIT. `git clone` works very fast, but `git svn clone` takes hours to finish. Would the cpu/ram increment help in this case?

Comment: serving svn with apache is not the best perf you can get, maybe look in this direction.

Answer (score 3):

Many our users reported that [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) works significantly faster when importing huge SVN repositories to Git.

If you're using Atlassian Stash for managing Git repositories, there's [SubGit plugin](http://subgit.com/stash/) that converts SVN repositories to Stash-managed Git repositories from the Web UI.

SubGit is a commercial software, but it is free for importing purposes. One has to pay only if one uses Git-SVN synchronization functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to have been a memory leak in old versions of `git-svn`.  See: [Resuming git-svn clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676912/resuming-git-svn-clone)

Comment: But finally the operation completed successfully. I am using latest v1.8.0.